# when i pass string from child process to parent process via shared memory

Tags: c, process

i am trying to pass a string from a child process to parent process and the parent process has to capitalise  that string from parent process ,but when the parent process receives the string i get segmentation fault when i use strlen. It is like parent process doesnt recognize the string that both parent and child use.
This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define SEM1KEY 1234
#define SEM2KEY 4321
#define SHM1KEY 5678
#define SHM2KEY 8765
#define SHM1SIZE sizeof(struct in_ds)
#define SHM2SIZE sizeof(struct out_ds)

typedef struct in_ds{
    pid_t pid;
    char *line;
}in_ds;

typedef struct out_ds{
    pid_t pid;
    char *cap_line;
}out_ds;

union semun{
    int val;
    struct semid_ds *buff;
    unsigned short *array;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n=5,k=5;

    int semid[2], shmid[2];
    int i, j, result, pid_match=0, overall_pid_match=0;
    union semun arg;
    struct sembuf oparray[2] = {{0,-1,0},{0,1,0}};
    char buffer[]="abcde", *c_line;
    pid_t pid;
    in_ds *inds;
    out_ds *outds;
    FILE *fp;
////////////////////shm//////////////////

    shmid[0] = shmget((key_t)1234,SHM1SIZE,IPC_CREAT|0600);
    if(shmid[0]==-1)
    {
        perror("shmget failed!");
        return -1;
    }

    shmid[1] = shmget((key_t)4321,SHM2SIZE,IPC_CREAT|0600);
    if(shmid[1]==-1)
    {
        perror("shmget failed!");
        return -1;
    }

    inds = (in_ds*)shmat(shmid[0],(in_ds*)0,0);
    outds = (out_ds*)shmat(shmid[1],(out_ds*)0,0);
    if(inds==NULL || outds==NULL)
    {
        printf("shmat failed!");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("ok1");
////////////////////sem///////////////////

    semid[0] = semget(SEM1KEY,1,IPC_CREAT|0600);
    if(semid[0]==-1)
    {
        perror("semget failed!");
        return -1;
    }

    semid[1] = semget(SEM2KEY,1,IPC_CREAT|0600);
    if(semid[1]==-1)
    {
        perror("semget failed!");
        return -1;
    }

    arg.val = 0;
    if(semctl(semid[0],0,SETVAL,arg)==-1)
    {
        perror("semaphore initialization failed!");
        return -1;
    }
    arg.val = 1;
    if(semctl(semid[1],0,SETVAL,arg)==-1)
    {
        perror("semaphore initialization failed!");
        return -1;
    }


    outds->pid = 0;
    inds->pid = 0;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid>0)
        {
            continue;       //parent
        }else if(pid == 0){
            break;          //child
        }else{
            printf("fork failed!");     //ERROR
            return -1;
        }
    }

    if(pid>0)           //C process
    {
        for(i=0; i<k+1; i++)
        {
            semop(semid[1],&oparray[0],1);      //down(sem2)

            if(inds->pid!=0)
            {
                c_line = malloc((strlen(inds->line)+1)*sizeof(char));       
                strcpy(c_line,inds->line);
                free(inds->line);

                j=0;
                while(c_line[j]!='\0')
                {
                    c_line[j] += -32;
                    j++;
                }


                outds->pid = inds->pid;
                outds->cap_line = malloc((strlen(c_line)+1)*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(outds->cap_line,c_line);
                free(c_line);

            }

            semop(semid[0],&oparray[1],1);      //up(sem1)
        }
    }else{
        fp = fopen("textfile","r");
        for(i=0; i<k; i++)
        {       
            printf("ok2");
            semop(semid[0],&oparray[0],1);      //down(sem1)

            if(outds->pid == 0)
            {}          
            else if(outds->pid == -1)
            {
                fclose(fp);
                exit(pid_match);
            }else{
                if(outds->pid == getpid())pid_match++;
                printf("Line:%s , pid:%d, mypid:%d",outds->cap_line,outds->pid,getpid());
                free(outds->cap_line);
            }


            inds->line = malloc((strlen(buffer)+1)*sizeof(char));
            strcpy(inds->line,buffer);
            inds->pid = getpid();
            semop(semid[1],&oparray[1],1);
        }
    }


    semctl(semid[0],0,IPC_RMID,0);
    semctl(semid[1],0,IPC_RMID,0);

    shmdt(inds);
    shmdt(outds);

    shmctl(shmid[0],IPC_RMID,NULL);
    shmctl(shmid[1],IPC_RMID,NULL); 
}

when i debug i see:

  Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
  strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
  106   ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S: No such file or directory.
  c_line = malloc((strlen(inds->line)+1)*sizeof(char));

this is the second time parent process is running
and it gets a string which is inds->line
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please add the error your getting?

Comment: You allocate enough shared memory for the `out_ds` and `in_ds` structures, but those contain pointers.  When your child process puts a pointer to their memory space into shared memory, there's no way for the parent to read that data.  The parent can read the pointer, but it is meaningless in the parent's address space.  And conversely for the child reading from the parent.  Redesign the `in_ds` and `out_ds` structures.  Add an actual array of characters instead of the pointer.